# Elastic Search Lowercase analyser does not return search result

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have a text based index like below. I am trying to maintain both exact search and ambiguous search based on tokens based on user input. While text based search works fine(partial search) when it comes to term search it returns data iff case is the same.
I did try adding a lowercase filter based analyzer but it does not help. What can I do here?

**Mappings:**

```
"project_title": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  },
  "projectabstract": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  },
```

**New index based on lowercase analyzer:**

```
PUT /project_term_search_text_analyzer
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt_standard": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"       
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {"project_title": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  },
  "projectabstract": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  },}
```

How should I update my index to work in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html) which works on the keyword fields. You can also customize your normalizer like analyzer, In the link you can find the relevant example with lowercase filter, which would solve your issue.

Comment: so I did try that, however if I add a lower case analyzer which works only on keywords from what I understand, ambiguous search breaks. How should I deal with that. Link to the jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/L7ckur9b/

Comment: Not sure how to approach here.

Comment: @LeoBabyJacob If I understand right, you want to use the exact search and partial search, correct on the same field ?

Comment: yes, Actually I think I figure out, I added the normalizer you mentioned above to the keyword section of the mapping. So if I want to do an exact search I am setting the field as "task_number.keyword" else for normal search I set "task_number". I am getting the results, but is this the standard way or is there a better way ?

Comment: @LeoBabyJacob, yes, this is the standard way and thats the reason Elasticsearch added `.keyword` field for every text field, if you don't define explicit mapping :)

Comment: also quick question, is it possible to specify the normalizer in a logstash configuration file. I am injesting data from a dbms and I was wondering if I need to do it everytime I injest data do I need to create a new index or is there a way that I can do it from logstash

Comment: @LeoBabyJacob, thanks for your kind words, i don't have much exp with logstash but ultimately logstash will be indexing and storing data in Elasticsearch, Stackoverflow if you define your Elasticsearch index with proper settings, you don't have to do anything..would advise you to test this out on sample data.

Comment: @LeoBabyJacob, let me know if you are able to solve it ..

Comment: I did some more research and I found out a way, so you can specify template => <filename containing mappings and settings> in output section of your logstash. There I was able to set normalizer to each of the keywords. Now I can properly injest data without having to tinker with ES in kibana directly for the settings and mappings

Comment: @LeoBabyJacob, Nice thanks for update, what you mentioned is a index template :)

Comment: thanks for all the help amit